# Unity C# : Changing state of tags multiple time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm new to both unity and c# .
i'm trying to make a text based game for practice .
the problem is different state of game have different number of buttons and i want to switch between these with Tags but it only works for the first state and then when i try to get to next state turn of all the buttons

here is the code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Textadvanture0 : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    Text text0;

    [SerializeField]
    Text text1;

    [SerializeField]
    Text text2;

    [SerializeField]
    Text text3;

    [SerializeField]
    Text text4;

    [SerializeField]
    State Startingstate;


    State state;

    string Flag;

    public void ManageStates(int cnt)
    {
        var nextstate = state.GetNextStates();
        if (cnt == 1) //left
        {
            state= nextstate[0];
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        state = Startingstate;
        FlagCheck();

    }


    void Update()
    {

       Debug.Log(state.GetChoiceN());

       FlagCheck();


        text0.text = state.GetStateStory(0);
        text1.text = state.GetStateStory(1);
        text2.text = state.GetStateStory(2);
        text3.text = state.GetStateStory(3);
        text4.text = state.GetStateStory(4);

    }


    void FlagDown()
    {
        GameObject[] gameObjectArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(Flag);

        foreach (GameObject go in gameObjectArray)
        {
            go.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    void FlagOn()
    {
        GameObject[] gameObjectArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(Flag);

        foreach (GameObject go in gameObjectArray)
        {
            go.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    void FlagCheck()
    {

        if (state.Choice == 1)
        {

            Flag = ("Mono Choice");
            FlagOn();

            Flag = ("Dual Choice");
            FlagDown();

            Flag = ("Triple Choice");
            FlagDown();

        }
        else if (state.Choice == 2)
        {
            Flag = ("Mono Choice");
            FlagDown();

            Flag = ("Dual Choice");
            FlagOn();

            Flag = ("Triple Choice");
            FlagDown();


        }
        else if (state.Choice == 3)
        {
            Flag = ("Mono Choice");
            FlagDown();

            Flag = ("Dual Choice");
            FlagDown();

            Flag = ("Triple Choice");
            FlagOn();

        }
    }
}
```

And State class :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "State")]
public class State : ScriptableObject
{
  [TextArea(10,14)]  [SerializeField] string[] StoryText;
  [SerializeField]
   public int Choice;
  [SerializeField]
  State [] Nextstates;



  public string GetStateStory(int Counter)
  {

      return StoryText[Counter];
  }


  public int GetChoiceN()
  {
      return Choice;
  }
  public State[] GetNextStates()
  {
      return Nextstates;
  }

}
```

by the way i get index was outside the bound of the array error as well but it doesn't seem to affect the game in any way
any solution would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you're getting is probably due to the arguments you're passing to the `TextArea`, the 10 to 14. If you have small blocks of text you may not have 14 lines.

Without seeing how you're using these classes in Unity, my guess for why states are not being updated is because you're setting the value of your `state` in 2 places, the `Start` method which only gets called once after the object is enabled, and in your `ManageStates` method which is only wired to handle a `cnt` value of `1`.

If the value of state.GetNextStates()[0] is the same state as the state that's loaded you won't see a change.

Comment: thanks for answer . States do update but buttons don't i think the fault is in FlagCheck function but i don't have any idea how to fix is

Comment: No, it's sequential. Any code you write in a block will be executed in order:
So
    ...
    {
        var value = 4;
        Debug.Log(value);
        value = 2;
        Debug.Log(value);
    }
    ...
should give you an output of:
    4
    2